# Java ASCII figure trouble

Tags: java, ascii, figure

I'm having trouble figuring out this last part. I have to create a slash ascii figure and be able to scale it up or down depending on the number passed in the method.
Here is the figure at size 4:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!//////
```

Size 5:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!!!!!//////
\\\\\\\\!!////////
```

Size 6:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!!!!!!!!!//////
\\\\\\\\!!!!!!////////
\\\\\\\\\\!!//////////
```

and so forth.
Here is the code I have so far

```
public static void Slash(int num){
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i*2; j++) {
            System.out.print("\\");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < - (i*4); j++) {
            System.out.print("!");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i*2; j++) {
            System.out.print("/");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what the expression should be in the for loop for the "!".

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I don't understand what you're asking about the code fragment that you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the total number of characters printed to be the same regardless of `i`.  (You seem to already know that; the loop bounds formally add to a constant 0 in your code.)  You just need to know what that constant is (as a function of `num`); try writing down the value from your three examples to see if there's an obvious pattern.

Comment: I understand that the amount of !'s increase by 4 for every size that it increases if that is what you are saying?

Comment: Never mind I figured out what you were saying, Thanks so much for your help. It was right in front of me the whole time and I just couldn't see it.